# Class being redeclared after include

Tags: php

I have the following include code on a page:

```
include "cc/ConstantContact.php";
```

This file exists and contains the lines:

```
require_once('Authentication.php');
require_once('Collections.php');
require_once('Components.php');
```

When I load the file that includes constantContact.php, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class OAuthException in /public_html/cc/Authentication.php on line 13

I do not understand how this class is being declared twice, as there is only the one time that the constantContact.php file includes Authentication.php.

These includes work just fine for me on other sites as well.

Comment: Are you including constantContact.php more than once?

Comment: Could ConstantContact.php have the same class name? In that case, you'd have to start using namespaces.

Comment: @Enstage  I am not including constantContact.php more than once.  My loading page just has that one include line for it, and that's all.

Comment: One of two things is happening - either 1) the file is being included more than once, or 2) there is a class/namespace clash. Considering it is throwing the error on `OAuthException` and not something like `Foo\Bar\OAuthException`, I'm guessing it's the latter. Search through your codebase for the string `class OAuthException` or if you can use regex `class.*OAuthException`, see if there's more than one instance matching. If that's the case, you need to namespace one or both of the classes.